# Customise eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to customize EGit eclipse plugin, to remove some commands from HistoryView. 
Which is the best approach to do this. I also want to do this in a way to be to easy update to a newer version.

Also please indicate a good book reference where I can find more about plugin developmentd

Comment: Did you locate the code where the commands are added to context menu?

Comment: Do you mean plugin.xml file?

Comment: Update the post and list all the commands you want to remove from history view

Comment: Push Commit... and Checkout

Comment: Yes, basically remove the parts from plugin.xml which adds the push,commit and checkout menu item. Why do you want to remove these menu items?

Comment: You will find good tutorials and books on http://www.vogella.com/